# Add Listview of parent site list

Tags: 2010, list, development, list-view, filter

I want to add a page where users can view and edit a list, problem is the list is not in the site but rather in its parent site. I also want to be able to filter the list so they can only see a items that have a predefined value in a certain column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try using Content Query Webpart(CQWP) in your site.
You can fetch data from your parent site by using it.

here is a link which might be helpful.

http://pravahaminfo.blogspot.in/2012/02/content-query-webpart-cqwp-in.html

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint out-of-the-box doesn't allow you to display list views from other sites.  You have a couple of options though:

1) Use a third-party tool

2) Write a custom web part or application page in Visual Studio that queries the list data from that site and displays it using a GridView or other control on the page.

Comment: is it possibly references and not a copy so they can still edit it ?

Comment: Using a third-party tool or writing some code to do it would query the list from the parent site (so it only exists in one place).  You could save it as a template and re-create the list in multiple places if you wanted (after each list was created, it would be independent of the template).

Comment: I understand but i would need it to be referenced, so when an element is modified in the child site the same element in the parent would also be. Is there a way to achieve this ? Linking the list on child page with a specific view that would have filters ? I can also deploy code i just dont know what to do in terms of design...

Comment: Right, so building a web part that queries your parent list and displays it in the web part would work.  Here are some tutorials to get you started: Custom Web Part (http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/02/15/intro-to-sharepoint-2010-development-how-to-build-and-deploy-a-web-part.aspx); Querying Lists from C# (http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/09/sharepoint-list-c-part-1.html).